# What are the safest kinds of authentication for a rtsp video stream? Any examples of URL implementations?

Tags: authentication, ssl, video, stream, rtsp

I use this kind of URL to get my camera video stream:

rtsp://192.168.1.10:554/user=admin&password=&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?

but I wonder if only using this login is safe and how to make the image access more secure. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Security for your video stream can focus on different areas - one is access/authentication and so long as you are passing the username and password over an encrypted link then this is a relatively standard level of security - having something more like two factor authentication would require a more complex set up which may be overkill for you.

Another is protecting the video stream itself from being interpreted, copied or redirected - the safest approach is to encrypt the video stream itself if your camera supports this (many good quality security cameras will). Without this, even if you authenticate the user you run the risk of someone being able to view the video stream. It is worth being aware that even if you use SRTP Secure Real Time Transport Protocol, the encryption features are optional so you need to make sure they are enabled for full security.

A third, and probably less usual concern but one which may be important depending on the application, is verifying that the video feed is actually coming from the camera or source you think it is. The typical approach to this is to have a key or certificate at the camera which it use to 'sign' or identify itself.